# My setup.exe is being blocked by anti virus only if downloaded frm my website

Tags: c#, exe, antivirus, copy-protection

I have setup.exe built using inno setup and the setup contains .net exe files with .exe being protected by 3rd party (shell protection).

When I downloaded setup from my own website, anti virus blocks the exe to run after installation.
In other hand, if I copy the setup.exe thru the pen drive to other pc then anti virus doesn't block my application but still it does checks for virus before running.

How to avoid anti virus blocking my application when downloaded from the website?

Comment: _make it FUD_ -  As in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt) or [this](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=FUD) or what???

Comment: What do you mean by FUD?

Comment: @TaW the second one, I'm sure of it.

Comment: Copying it to a FAT32 file system and back is the slow way.  Quicker to right-click the file > Properties > click Unblock.  Removes the "this file came from the Internet and is therefore not trustworthy" alternate data stream.

Comment: What to unblock. As i will be uploading my application to internet. I can't all the users to disable AV OR unblock etc ...

Comment: The days that anybody downloads a setup.exe file from the Internet and thinks "meh, what can go wrong, this will probably not mess up my machine" are long gone.

Comment: @Hans: While true I'd rather see advice on how to proceed best or what to specifically to avoid..

Comment: I'd rather have a pony.